# UIButtons vs images(or UIViews) w/Gesture Recognizers - efficiency

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer

We have UIButtons that perform actions and TapGestureRecognizers applied to many of the UIViews. Now, where I am confused is, which of them performs tasks more efficiently. Will more buttons on a view increase the memory load of an app more than using gesture recognisers.

I hope i am clear with my doubt. A brief but to the point insight to this will really be appreciated.

Comment: I don't expect either actions or gesture recognizers to be a performance or memory problem in your application. That said, if you do experience a problem the only way to know the cause is to measure (use Instruments).

Comment: Alright! I was timid about their performance on memory

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the UX/accessibility implications of using a gesture recogniser when you should really have a button.